# ffmpeg cut video and put audio in the middle of it

Tags: ffmpeg

I have

- a video file of 60s duration.
- an audio file of 35s duration

I want to cut a video from 5th second to 50th and put an audio file in the middle that starts playing at 5th second of the output. So first 5 and last 5 seconds output video is silent. I also don't want to reencode the video so compilation would be fast and quality would stay exactly the same.

[image]

I'm trying the following command

`ffmpeg -y -i DJI_0325.mp4 -ss 00:00:40.5 -i song.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4`

but the audio starts playing in the middle.
I also tried different combination of the things below, but no luck :(

- `-async 1` `-map 0:v:0`
- `-c:v copy -c:a copy`
- different sets of `-ss` and `-to`

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -y -i DJI_0325.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -shortest -itsoffset 00:00:05 -i song.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a mp3 -af "volume=enable='lte(55,t)':volume=0" out.mp4
```

`-stream_loop -1` Enables looping on the following input.
`-shortest` Selects the shortest input to be looped to the duration of the longest input (Otherwise it will loop forever).
`-itsoffset HH:MM:SS` Shifts the following input forward to start at HH:MM:SS.
`-af "volume=enable='lte(55,t)':volume=0"` Mutes the audio starting at 55 seconds.

I couldn't find a way to set an input duration that does't apply on the output but this gets you the result you want.
 Personally I would recommend you to create the audio in the duration you want first and only use the -itsoffet flag.